# Enum in Rust language

Tags: rust, enums

Why is `size_of::<demo>() == 48`

```
enum demo{
    a(String),
    b(String, String)
}
```

and on the other hand `size_of::<demo2>() == 56`

```
enum demo2{
    a(String),
    b(String, String),
    c(i8)
}
```

I am confused by those two examples. Shouldn't they be the same size?

Comment: Why do you think they should be the same size if they are different enums?

Comment: Might be that the compiler doesn't know any way to niche-value-optimise the third one: A and B can be differentiated by the second half being all zero (or at least the second String's pointer being null), it basically simplifies to `(String, Option<String>)` so the NVO on option-like type might trigger. When you add a third variant, there is no 3-values niche which the compiler can use, by hand you could "split" the niche value but I don't think the compiler has the knowledge to do that. Thus the compiler needs an explicit tag byte.

Comment: as enum takes the maximum size of any value in all possible values. So in both cases, the maximum size is of (String, String) which is 48 so why the second one is giving the size 56?

Comment: Not quite it also has to differentiate the variants so without niche optimization there has to be a discriminant, padded to the alignment of the values contained so that's `8 (discriminant) + 2*24 (values) = 56` bytes for the non optimized `demo2` but only `2*24 (values) = 48` for `demo` where it found a niche.

Comment: What is NVO?
can you pls share some details about it.
@cafce25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `String` is represented internally as a struct with three values:

- A non-null pointer to the string bytes.
- The length of the string, in bytes, as a `usize`.
- The allocated space of the block of memory, as a `usize`.

In a 64-bit system, each of these needs 8-bytes, so `3 * 8 = 24 bytes` in total.

If you have two of these, then `2 * 24 = 48 bytes`. That is the length of your `demo` type.

But where does the compiler store wether it is a `demo::a` or `demo::b`? Here is where that `NVO` or *Niche Value Optimization* comes into play. The trick is that the pointer *inside the string* is a [NonNull](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html) pointer, that cannot have the `null` value, even if the string is unallocated.

That impossible value is called a *niche* value and can be used by the compiler to signal which enum value is really there. In your particular case, when storing a `demo::a` it can set the memory used for the pointer of the second string to `null`. And obviously when it stores a `demo::b` it will be non-null.

About your second example `demo2`, it has three enum values, so it need at least 2 bits to store the discriminant. It could conceivably use one of the `String` pointers for one bit and the other for the other bit, but as far as I know the compiler won't collect bits from different niches to do NVO, so that will not do.

And if with `demo2` you do not have NVO, then you need 24 bytes for each string plust 1 byte for the enum discriminant, that is `2 * 24 + 1 = 49`... but we are forgetting the alignment! In Rust, as in C, the size of a type must be a multiple of its alignment (that is necessary to be able to build arrays, for example). The alignment of `demo2` is the biggest alignment of any of its members, and the alignment of an 64-bit pointer is usually 8. The smallest multiple of 8 greater or equal than 49 is **56**, so that is the size that you get.

Comment: if using a null value solves the problem, why this is taking extra discriminant?

`enum demo3{
    a(String),
    b(String, String),
    c(String, String,String)
}
`
it is giving size as 80 bytes,why it is not using NULL value for that ?

Comment: A NonNull pointer has only one bit worth of _niche value_: either it is null or it is not, one bit of niche allows you to make two discriminants, if you have three enum values, then that is not enough and the compiler must store the discriminant as its own value.